# Hadoop Yarn Stuck at Running Job Ubuntu

Tags: linux, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hadoop-yarn

I was trying to run **single mode pseudo distributed** mode hadoop on ec2 ubuntu machine on a simple task. However my program is stuck at running jobs. I attach my linux screen and Resourcemanager page here.Any idea is appreciated. Thanks.

**Add1: the other thing I found is the NodeManager disappears when I type jps (It was there the first time I type jps but disappears later)**

**Add2: I checked nodemanager log and noticed that it was shutdown due to that minimum allocation is not satisfied, though I had changed scheduler minimum mb to 128 and vcore to 1 in yarn-site.xml**

[image: linux screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: img]

Comment: Where it says `Connecting to ResourceManager at /`... That should be an actual address, not `0.0.0.0:8032`. The image even tells you that it is waiting to connect to the ResourceManager (RM), but it cannot with that given address in your yarn-site... If you want to use Amazon services, they give you EMR so you don't have to configure this all yourself

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for your comment. So I should configure the address in yarn-site.xml file? Yes you are right that I can use EMR but this is part of my cloud computing course homework where I have to configure it myself.

Comment: Yes, the `yarn.resourcemanager.hostname` defaults to `0.0.0.0`, and `yarn.resourcemanager.address` defaults to `${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8032`

Comment: @cricket_007 change the hostname doesn't solve my problem. One thing I just realize is when I start-yarn.sh, I have NodeManager running. However when I type jps seconds after that, the node manager disappear...i am not sure why this is happening. Do you have any idea? Thank you very much

Comment: Somewhere in `/var/log` should give you a good idea of what to diagnose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved my own problem above.

1. Added details to the problem statement above, I later found my node manager didn't start well (first time type jps, node manager is there as shown in the attached picture. However, it disappeared seconds after that. I found this by type jps many times).
2. I checked the node manager log and found the error is **"doesn't satisfy minimum allocations, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager"**
3. I searched on the internet and found the solution is adding the following property into yarn-site.xml file

yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb

value is 1024

yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores

value is 1

[image]

4. Then restart start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh. If you get into hostname:8088, you would see the **memory total** and **total vcores** total should be larger than 0 now and you can run an application

[image]

PS: my application was stuck at map 0% and reduce 0% initially. Then I simply change 1024 to 4096, 1 to 2 above. Then I can successfully run a map reduce program on my ec2 instance (single node pseudo distributed)